# flexが効かない

Tags: html, css

均等に横並びに配置するために、下記のようにコードを書いたのですがflexが適用されません。もしこのコードをみて改善策がわかる方がいたら教えてください。　
よろしくお願いします。

```html
<nav class="global-nav_items">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">acess</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
.global-nav_item{
    padding: 40px;
}
.global-nav_item .nav-list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.global-nav_item .nav-list>li{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 80px;
    list-style: none;
}
.global-nav_item .nav-list> li :last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: 動かないので直してくれというよりも先に, 基礎的なことをまずよく読んで理解することが大切な気がします。[フレックスボックス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) について。
簡単な例の紹介の中の縦並びのソース [flexbox0.html](https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/main/css/css-layout/flexbox/flexbox0.html)。横並びなら `section { display: flex;}` 追加するだけ

Answer (score 0):

綴りミスではないでしょうか。
HTMLでは `class="global-nav_items"`、CSS では `.global-nav_item` (`s`がない)となっています。

ブラウザの開発者ツールで `.nav-list` の要素を調べると `display: flex` が適用されていないことが確認できます。そのことから、`display: flex` を含むルールセットのセレクタが間違っている可能性が高く、クラス名の不一致に気づけるかもしれません。